# How to iterate a text value to Active Record Model name format in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `dialog popup` comes by `model name`. For example,

```
<%= link_to pro_generic_lookup_data_path("Enr::Rds::Question2009", format: :js), data: {remote: true}, id: "question_picker" do %>
      <%= f.label :Question, class: 'question_label'%>
      <%= f.text_field :Question, class: 'question_label'%>
<% end %>
```

I have the three `section` like this. I am getting the value in `javascript` and insert into the `fields` inside the `link_to` method.

But the last `section`, would get the `question_id` and match the text in `answer_column`. The `answer_column` has the values of the `Model's` name like `enr_rds_question_t`. So, I should get this text and change into the model name like Enr::Rds::Question and make the `link_to` like to open the `dialog popup` box for `answers`.

I am new to RoR, So apologize for that am not able to explain clearly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crude way though

```
'enr_rds_question'.split('_t')[0].split('_').collect{|s| s.camelize}.join("::").constantize
```

Comment: Thanks, Some times the text coming like enr_rds_question_t.

Comment: what is 't' here is it a module or class ? or is it the case where you want to ignore that '_t' ?

Comment: @Vinay could you please tell exact scenario instead of sometime?

Comment: @Ross - 't' defines the table. Sometimes, its would comes with the end of the text. So, I just want to remove the '_t'. If its not have the '_t', then i just want to change the normal text into the Model name. Thanks

Comment: @Soundar . Hi, Will you please come into the chat room. I can explain you in detail. Please?

Answer (score 2):

```
 "enr_rds_question_t".split('_t').first.split('_').map(&:camelize).join('::').constantize
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your own like

```
"enr_rds_question".gsub("_", " " ).titleize.gsub(" ", "::" )
```

OR Ref [`camelize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#M000708)

```
"enr_rds_question".gsub("_", "\" ).camelize
```

Comment: Thanks, Some times the text coming like enr_rds_question_t.

Comment: So what is expected in such cases? above will return `Enr::Rds::Question::T`

Comment: No, if its would come with `_t`, that should be removed. Thanks